# Can make calls in Teams but cannot receive calls

Tags: windows-10

A coworker brought her daughters notebook in today with a strange problem. Her daughter uses the notebook for school and due to the current pandemic, the school wants to use Teams for meetings. She can make a call in Teams to other people, but other people cannot call her.

She's using the online version of Teams, I've already downloaded the client and installed it, but that doesn't make a difference.

I've verified the basics: yes, the notebook does have internet access, her status is set to "available", she is able to call other people, and everything looks normal as far as I can tell. However, when I try to make a call from my laptop to her, I get the message that the person I'm trying to call is not available.

I'd like to help her, but unfortunately I have no idea what's wrong, let alone how to solve it. Does anybody have any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: May be the account exists two times and she is logged in with account2 and all people are trying to call account1 (which is of course offline at it is not used). Otherwise the causes are manifold. Could be the used Wifi, the used Internet access (e.g. a DS-Lite system). Replace those potential problem causing parts witha different to see if it makes a difference (e.g. use a cable instead of Wifi or try a different Internet access, ..)

Comment: In the Settings -> Calls. Verify that on the "Call answering rules" section, `Calls ring me` is selected and not `Forward my calls`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I've checked them, but to no avail. This morning my coworker told me that she asked someone else who checked the notebook and changed a setting in the Windows Action Centre, which solved the issue. Unfortunately she couldn't tell me which setting, so I'm afraid I can't post the hint here for future reference.